# How to get data from different microservices which are using dynamo db

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-dynamodb, microservices

I am developing a micro-service architecture. I have two different services let's say one for dog and other for event in which dogs will participate

I am using dynamoDB. So the current structure is something like

```
Table 1- Dog {dogid, dogname, dogprofilepic, dog_age, dog_price}

Table 2- Event{eventid, eventname, eventdescription, eventdate,dogid}
```

Where dogid is of list type it will contain something like {1,2,3,4}. Basically list of id of dogs which are going to participate in this event.

Now there is an event in which 10 Dogs will participate. We need to show data combined from these two different microservice.

DynamoDB does not support joins and i want to know best workflow which gives me the dogname, dogprofilepic, dogage, dogprice along with event information such as eventname, eventdescription, eventdate

Please suggest the best way to achieve this keeping the number of read & write operation to minimum plus if i want to avoid this handling of data on the application end.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: As asked, your question is incomplete. For instance: "Now i want to write a most optimized API which gives me the dogname, dogprofilepic, dogage, dogprice along with event information such as eventname, eventdescription, eventdate" is not a well specified query - are you looking for this information given a dog id, an event id, for all dogs? for all events?

Comment: @MikeDinescu: Yes i have a screen in application which shows you events with detail of dogs which are participating in that event.

Comment: I recommend you update the question with these details. Please be as specific asnpossible about the different ways you want to query the data. Also, try to include details about the number of dogs per event and the number of distinct events the same dog may participate in

Comment: these has been updated @MikeDinescu

Comment: these has been updated @MikeDinescu